# How to refresh remote file contents

Tags: samba, cifs

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dev system, which shares some folders via Samba (samba 2:4.3.9+dfsg amd64). I mount such a share on a different Ubuntu system (`mount -t cifs -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g),domain=DEVHOST,username=guest //DEVHOST/share /mnt/share`). All is well, mostly. But sometimes, when I edit the file on the dev system (via Vim), the changes aren't reflected on the client, i.e. the client sees the old file contents for quite some time.

`ll` shows that the file modification date hasn't been updated. However, a newly created file in the same directory is shown. But still the file contents of the existing file aren't updated. With `less`, I see additional null bytes (`^@`) at the end of the file, as many as the file size has increased by the edit.

I guess I see a stale cache. How do I instruct the client to reload the file from the remote Samba server? On the desktop, I would try refreshing via <kbd>F5</kbd> in Nautilus, but I'm logged into the client via SSH.

Note: This isn't a permanent problem; after a client reboot, things work fine again (for some time at least). I'm just wondering whether there's a better fix than forcibly unmounting / remounting, or even rebooting the client. Any hints what could be the root cause are welcome.

Comment: Check `man mount.cifs` and the `cache=` option; also the _CACHE COHERENCY_ section.

Comment: BTW, this is sometimes a problem with NFS as well.

Answer (score 3):

> Any hints what could be the root cause are welcome.

I ran into an issue somewhat like this once.  Turns out one host did not have an accurate clock.  Enabling `ntp` on all hosts corrected the issue.

> How do I instruct the client to reload the file from the remote Samba server?

Is your file reloaded & updated by running `env stat $FILE` ?   I suspect not.

Is the file updated on the client by releasing any opportunistic lock (oplock) on the file?
From `man mount.cifs`:

```
The CIFS protocol mandates (in effect) that the client should not
cache file data unless it holds an opportunistic lock (aka oplock) 
or a lease. Both of these entities allow the client to guarantee         
certain types of exclusive access to a file so that it can access its   
contents without needing to continually interact with the server.
```

I've seen synchronization issues between my windows7 box and Google Drive until I exit my copy of gvim (simply closing the buffer did not unlock the file and update Google Drive).  If you edit the file with vim on DEVHOST and then close vim, does the problem persist at the client?

As mentioned in the comments by @StephenHarris, edit the `mount` command above and try adding `-o cache=none`

From `man mount.cifs`:

```
cache=
    Cache mode. See the section below on CACHE COHERENCY for details. 
    Allowed values are:
    ·   none: do not cache file data at all
    ·   strict: follow the CIFS/SMB2 protocol strictly
    ·   loose: allow loose caching semantics
    The default in kernels prior to 3.7 was "loose". 
    As of kernel 3.7 the default is "strict".
```

---

Comment: oh man, I have ran to so many issues because of lack of accurate timing between the systems. Thanks a lot for the `ntp` hint!